# Alternative proof for chains

Tags: elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(X,\le)$ be a chain, $S\subseteq X$, and suppose $\sigma=\sup S$ exists. Then for every $x\in X$ with $x<\sigma$, there is some $s\in S$ s.t. $x<s\le\sigma$.
By contradiction:  Let $x\in X$ s.t. $x<\sigma$ and suppose for every $s\in S,x\not<s$, i.e. $x\ge s$. Then $x$ is an upper bound of $S$ but $x<\sigma$, contradiction.

I want to know if there's a quick alternative direct proof instead of proof by  contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can phrase just the same proof such that at least it doesn't sound like it's by contradiction:

Because $x<\sigma$, $x$ is not an upper bound for $S$. So there exists $s\in S$ such that $x<s$. However $\sigma$ *is* an upper bound for $S$, so $s\le\sigma$.

---

One may nitpick and claim there is a proof-by-contradiction hidden in the step from "not all $s\in S$ are $\le x$" to "there is an $s\in S$ with $s>x$". But in general, worrying unduly about whether this or that proof is by contradiction or not is a bit of a fool's errand unless you're going all the way and explicitly select your definition of concepts such as "chain" and "upper bound" or "supremum" while keeping *carefully* track of minor difference in the wording that matters intuitionistically, but *did not* matter to the authors of the textbooks you're otherwise getting those definitions from ...

Comment: A lot of proofs involving relations are by contradiction, and maybe there's no way to avoid it. I was curious to see if it could be done and it seems like it can, but wouldn't be useful. Thanks for the info.